# Crud esta dando erro na linha onde tem o forEach?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Estou estudando criação de *Crud* com *Php* e *Bootstrap*, e quando o arquivo  *menu_admin* e aberto no navegador ele da esse erro:

> Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\menu_admin.php on line 44

Link do *github*, quem puder me ajudar agradeço muito !!!

https://github.com/rockout13/crud

eu alterei o que falaram, mas apareceu outro problema, seria a query que esta falhando ?

`Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\menu_admin.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\menu_admin.php on line 45`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `query` do `PDO` não retorna nada [veja aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php), ele apenas executa a `query`. O que vai te retornar as linhas que vieram do banco de dados em um `array` são os métodos `fetch`, no exemplo abaixo vou fazer com o `fetchAll`:

```
include 'banco.php';
$pdo = Banco::conectar();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pessoa ORDER BY id DESC';

foreach($pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['nome'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['CPF'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Endereço'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Listar</a>';
    echo ' ';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Atualizar</a>';
    echo ' ';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Excluir</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<tr>';
}
```

Comment: Apenas colocando "->" no foreach($pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){

Comment: Vlw, acabei misturando outras linguagens kkk

Comment: Resposta editada

Comment: eu alterei o que falaram, mas apareceu outro problema, seria a query que esta falhando ?



`Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\menu_admin.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\menu_admin.php
on line
45`

Comment: Provavelmente, porque quando a `query` da erro retornar `false`, como `false` é do tipo `boolean`, não tem a função `fetchAll`. Tente executar a `query` direto no banco.